# CodeLite opencv path

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, codelite

I am trying to use OpenCV framework in CodeLite. I am a MacOS user.

I downloaded OpenCV 4.1.0 on the official website, and it contains opencv2.framework. But, I couldn't find a way to include it in my CodeLite project. I tried setting  Linker Options and Libraries Search Paths, but it didn't work. When I tried to run a cpp file, It keeps giving me (because of `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>`)
'opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found error.

When I try on terminal however, I could manage to compile and run a sample code. This is what I tried on terminal

```
g++ $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4) -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main
```

How can I use opencv2.framework file on CodeLite for C++?

Or, Is there a way to configure CodeLite compiler such that it runs the exact expression that worked for terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently had a similar problem trying to compile a C++ codelite project which uses OpenCV 4.1.0 on a Mac. After some trial and error, the following steps resolved it:

1. create a new folder /usr/local/opencv2
2. copy the contents of /Library/Frameworks/opencv2.framework/Versions/A/Headers into that new folder
3. in codelite, set the linker options for the release build of the project to:

   -F/Library/Frameworks -framework opencv2 -framework CoreMedia -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreVideo -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreFoundation -framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL -framework IOKit -framework OpenCL -framework Foundation -framework Accelerate